# List Strange Unexplained

Tags: python, list

Can you please explain this to me, I'm completely lost here.

This is my code:

```
def ff(L):
    for a in L:
        k = L.index(a)
        print(k)
        b = L.pop(k)
        g = b
        print(g)
        L.insert(k,g)

    return L
```

This is the output:

```
>>> L = [12,13,14]
>>> ff(L)
0
12
1
13
2
14
[12, 13, 14]
```

But when i do this:

```
def ff(L):
    for a in L:
        k = L.index(a)
        print(k)
        b = L.pop(k)
        g = b + 1
        print(g)
        L.insert(k,g)
    return L
```

output:

```
>>> L = [12,13,14]
>>> ff(L)
0
13
0
14
0
15
[15, 13, 14]
```

Why So?

Comment: Well, what's different between the two code samples? Why would that change what's happening?

Comment: I can't say I understand the specifics of this problem, but in general, modifying a list while you're iterating over it, can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 5):

It' quite obvious. You can add more print to your code to see reasons yourself:

```
>>> def ff(L):
...     for a in L:
...         k = L.index(a)
...         print 'value', a, 'at', k, 'pos in', L,
...         b = L.pop(k)
...         g = b + 1
...         print 'list after pop', L,
...         L.insert(k,g)
...         print 'inserted value', g, 'list after ins', L
...     return L
...
>>> ff(L)
value 12 at 0 pos in [12, 13, 14] list after pop [13, 14] inserted value 13 list after ins [13, 13, 14]
value 13 at 0 pos in [13, 13, 14] list after pop [13, 14] inserted value 14 list after ins [14, 13, 14]
value 14 at 0 pos in [14, 13, 14] list after pop [13, 14] inserted value 15 list after ins [15, 13, 14]
[15, 13, 14]
```

So you basically look for a value, pop it, insert value+1 at first position, look for value+1 and further.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what's the question here, but as you incremented the value in the first iteration the item at 0th index becomes 13. And during the second iteration `L.index(13)` returns the index 0 again, so in the second iteration you modified the item at index 0 again to 14. And this goes on...

```
def ff(L):
    for a in L:
        print 'List', L, 'searching for', a, 'found at', L.index(a)
        k = L.index(a)
        b = L.pop(k)
        g = b + 1

        L.insert(k,g)
    return L
L = [12,13,14]
print ff(L)
```

**Output:**

```
List [12, 13, 14] searching for 12 found at 0
List [13, 13, 14] searching for 13 found at 0
List [14, 13, 14] searching for 14 found at 0
[15, 13, 14]
```

So, `list.index()` always returns the index of first match found, that's why in the second case the item at 0th index gets incremented.

---

A simple solution to increment all values by 1 will be:

```
>>> L = [12,13,14]
>>> [x+1 for x in L]
[13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Another solution is iterating over an copy of the list, `L[:]`, or by using something like `enumerate()`.